# Classes and input as value

Tags: python, class

I have this problem.

I have been playing around with this very short program, which can do a calculation for me with my own inputs.

I first tried just with a while loop outside a class, which works.

```
while True:
  try: 
      def get_result(number1, number2):
          result = number1 / number2
          return result

      number1 = int(input("What is your first number "))
      number2 = int(input("What is your second number "))

      results = get_result(number1, number2)
      break

  except: 
      number1 or number2 == int(0)
      print("You cannot use 0")

  print(results)
```

I wanted to create it inside a class, but cannot get it to work.

```
class Calculation():
  while True:
      try: 
          def __init__(self, number1, number2):
              self.number1 = number1
              self.number2 = number2
        
          def get_result(self):
              result = number1 / number2
              return result

          number1 = int(input("What is your first number "))
          number2 = int(input("What is your second number "))
        
          break

      except: 
          number1 or number2 == int(0)
          print("Dette går ikke. Du må ikke bruge 0")

calculation = Calculation()
print("resultatet er %d" % calculation.get_result())
```

The error is that it requires two value arguments, which I understand. But I want to use my input values as my value arguments. Is there something I have misunderstood?

Thank you!

Comment: Separate the loop from the class definition.  It does not make sense to have them combined like this.  You want to create a `Calculation` instance *from* the user input: `calculation = Calculation(number1, number2)`

Comment: I'm confused by some of your code. What is `number1 or number2 == int(0)` supposed to do? You say "The error is that it requires two value arguments" but what is "it"? Why is your `__init__` three layers deep?

Comment: Adding onto @0x5453 you could have those instaces created in the `__init__` if you really wanted to... but that would be hacky

Comment: @Nathan number1 or number2 == int(0) is made, so that you cannot divide with 0. With "it" I mean calculation = Calculation() - I just should have specified that. Sorry!

Comment: @0x5453 Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @KasperHøxbroeJeppesen but it doesn't do anything... There is no if statement attached to it

Comment: And using `try except` is generally bad practice, you could replace it with an if statement checking if it's ok before passing it on to the calculation

Comment: @Nathan I see your point with the if statement. Why is try except bad pratice ? Wouldn't you like to use that when you are working with inputs?

Comment: @KasperHøxbroeJeppesen I'll post an answer trying to explain

Comment: @Thank you! I appreciate it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, to answer the question. I'd rewrite it like this:

```
def get_non_zero_int():
    while True:
        number = input('Fill in a non zero integer value')
        if number.isdigit() or (number.startswith('-') and number[1:].isdigit()):
            if int(number) == 0:
                print('Number cannot be 0')
            else:
                return int(number)
        print("Please input an integer like: 1, 25, 160, etc.")


class Calculation:
    def __init__(self, number1, number2):
        self.number1 = number1
        self.number2 = number2

    def get_result(self):
        result = self.number1 / self.number2
        return result


number1 = get_non_zero_int()
number2 = get_non_zero_int()

calculation = Calculation(number1=number1, number2=number2)
print("resultatet er %d" % calculation.get_result())
```

What I've done is I've split up the part that gets the input numbers and then passes it on to the calculation class.

---

Why to avoid `try except`:

There are a number of reasons to avoid a `try except` block.

- it can have strange side effects
- it can hide bugs (eg: it will run, but the results will be wrong)
- it is difficult to read/understand what it's used for
- it is slow

Try to use if statements to check if everything is ok whenever possible.

If you have to use a try except, specify as accurately as possible was exception you are checking for. This prevents weird bugs being caused by the exception catching the wrong exceptions and will make it clearer for others what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. The way you created the get_non_zero_int function makes much more sense. I will remember to avoid the try and except for future work! Thank you! It really helped clear the things up for me!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this up and made it work, if you want the inputs to stay tell me and I can fix it.

```
class Calculation:
    def __init__(self):
        self.number1 = input("What is your first number: ")
        self.number2 = input("What is your second number: ")

    def get_result(self):
        try:
            result = float(self.number1) / float(self.number2)
            return result

        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print("Dette går ikke. Du må ikke bruge 0")


calculation = Calculation()
print("resultatet er %d" % calculation.get_result())
```

Comment: It seemed you asked for two numbers when creating the class, and then redefined them with the inputs. I got rid of the inputs.

Comment: Thank you! I would like the inputs. The inputs is what gives me problems.

Comment: This is the way I felt worked best. I got rid of the while loop, fixed the try and except, and now it has inputs for numbers.

Comment: Thank you! But is the input included?

Comment: In the init function

Comment: Thank you! Ofcourse, I see it now. Now it make sense to me! :)